# Openssl s_server ticket validation

Tags: tls, openssl

How does Openssl's s_server validate session tickets? I started up an s_server and stored the session ticket in a file, and then shutdown the s_server and started up a new server with the same command. This new server won't accept the old ticket, even though I started up both servers with the same certificates and key files.

To be specific, if I startup a server with this command:

```
openssl s_server -accept 8000 -cert test_cert.pem -key test_key.pem localhost
```

And connect to the server with a client:

```
 openssl s_client -sess_out session_ticket localhost:8000
```

Shutdown the server and then restart it again with the same command and then try to use the old session ticket with the new server:

```
 openssl s_client -sess_in session_ticket localhost:8000
```

The result is that the connection does a full handshake and not a resumption handshake. So why is the old session ticket not valid if both servers are using the same certificate credentials?

Comment: Tickets are encrypted under a symmetric key held by the server, and OpenSSL `s_server` creates this key ephemerally so you don't have to manage it manually, but this means each time you run the program the key is different and old tickets don't work. (Also note `s_client -sess_out/in` only saves a _ticket_ if the server provides one, which `s_server` does but other servers often don't; otherwise it saves and restores a client-side session object -- basically session-id and master-secret -- which must match a server session object to work.)

Comment: FWIW if you configure both server and client with the same _PSK_ secret, and enable PSK-based ciphersuite(s) at least for 1.2 and below (for 1.3 it might be automatic?), that should work over multiple program executions.